# JavaScript Tabs: onclick not executing function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a tab system on my website that should show the content of two different tabs `onclick`, but when I click it it doesn't work. I think there is something wrong with my `document.getElementById("tutorial").onclick = function()` and `document.getElementById("editor").onclick = function()` but I can't seem to see what at the moment.

Here is my code:

```js
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("tutorial").onclick = function() {
    openTab(event, 'tutorial');
}

document.getElementById("editor").onclick = function() {
    openTab(event, 'editor');
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 0.1s;
    animation: fadeEffect 0.1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/main.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" id="defaultOpen">Tutorial</button>
    <button class="tablinks">Editor</button>
  </div>

  <div id="tutorial" class="tabcontent">
    {{ content }}
  </div>

  <div id="editor" class="tabcontent">
    Editor 
  </div>
  
  <script src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Please help

Comment: use `javascript` code in `document.ready` function.

Comment: You put your onclick events on the content containers not on your tabs. Also your click handlers don't have an event argument defined should be `function(event) {`

Comment: @AsifSharifShahid that doesn't seem to work for me. Please post an answer which code that works please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set your click handlers on the `div`s with the content, not the tabs. I've modified your code to add IDs to the tabs themselves and set up click handlers there instead.

(Note that I also changed the `defaultOpen` ID, since elements can only have one ID each, and I added the ID `tutorialTab`.)

I also passed through `event` as pointed out by others.

```js
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("tutorialTab").onclick = function(event) {
    openTab(event, 'tutorial');
}

document.getElementById("editorTab").onclick = function(event) {
    openTab(event, 'editor');
}

document.getElementById("tutorialTab").click();
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 0.1s;
    animation: fadeEffect 0.1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/main.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks defaultOpen" id="tutorialTab">Tutorial</button>
    <button class="tablinks" id="editorTab">Editor</button>
  </div>

  <div id="tutorial" class="tabcontent">
    {{ content }}
  </div>

  <div id="editor" class="tabcontent">
    Editor 
  </div>
  
  <script src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
document.getElementById("tutorialBtn").onclick = function(event) {
    openTab(event, 'tutorial');
}

document.getElementById("editorBtn").onclick = function(event) {
    openTab(event, 'editor');
}


<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" id="tutorialBtn">Tutorial</button>
    <button class="tablinks" id="editorBtn">Editor</button>
</div>
```

You forgot to pass `event` to the function on click. Passing event should fix the issue.

Comment: while not having an event parameter was a problem, the main issue is that OP has `tutorial` and `editor` id's as the content divs and not the tabs

Comment: You edited the wrong string in the second handler setup... should be `...getElementById("editorBtn")` and `openTab(..., 'editor')`.